# Is the fine-structure constant a parameter of the standard model?

Tags: standard-model, physical-constants

According to the [wikipedia entry on the fine-structure constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fine_structure_constant#Physical_interpretations):

> In fact, α is one of the about 20 empirical parameters in the Standard Model of particle physics, whose value is not determined within the Standard Model.

but, the [wikipedia list of parameters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model#Theoretical_aspects) does not mention α:

```
me  Electron mass       511 keV
mμ  Muon mass       105.7 MeV
mτ  Tau mass        1.78 GeV
mu  Up quark mass   μMS = 2 GeV     1.9 MeV
md  Down quark mass     μMS = 2 GeV     4.4 MeV
ms  Strange quark mass  μMS = 2 GeV     87 MeV
mc  Charm quark mass    μMS = mc    1.32 GeV
mb  Bottom quark mass   μMS = mb    4.24 GeV
mt  Top quark mass  On-shell scheme     172.7 GeV
θ12     CKM 12-mixing angle         13.1°
θ23     CKM 23-mixing angle         2.4°
θ13     CKM 13-mixing angle         0.2°
δ   CKM CP-violating Phase      0.995
g1 or g'    U(1) gauge coupling     μMS = mZ    0.357
g2 or g     SU(2) gauge coupling    μMS = mZ    0.652
g3 or gs    SU(3) gauge coupling    μMS = mZ    1.221
θQCD    QCD vacuum angle        ~0
v   Higgs vacuum expectation value      246 GeV
mH  Higgs mass      ~ 125 GeV (tentative)
```

Is α one of the basic parameters of the Standard Model?

If not, then is there a simple formula for α in terms of these other parameters?

(My guess is that α can be derived from g1/g2/g3.  However, I have been unable to find an explicit formula so far.)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your guess is correct. After electroweak symmetry breaking, the coupling constant for the residual $U(1)_\textrm{EM}$ gauge group can be written as a function of the couplings of the broken $SU(2)_L \times U(1)_\textrm{Y}$ gauge groups:
$$
\alpha = \frac{1}{4\pi}\frac{g^2 g\prime^2}{g^2+g\prime^2} = \frac{e^2}{4\pi}
$$

These couplings, however, are *running parameters*, defined at a particular energy scale. In your table, the energy scale is $\mu=M_Z$.  If you plugged in the numbers from your table, you would calculate $\alpha$ at $\mu=M_Z$, which is $\alpha(\mu=M_Z) \approx 1/128$.

The fine-structure constant is usually considered to be the *IR fixed-point* of $\alpha$, which is $\alpha(\mu = m_e) = 1/137$, i.e., $\alpha$ at low energy. To calculate this from your table, you would have to run $e$ to a lower energy scale, with the $\beta$-function:
$$
\frac{\partial e(\mu)}{\partial \log \mu} \equiv \beta(e) = \frac{e(\mu)^3}{12\pi^2}
$$
With this, and your knowledge of $\alpha(\mu=M_Z)$, you could recover $\alpha(\mu = m_e)= 1/137$.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I've been searching for!  Do you happen to have a link to a web page where I should have been able to find these formulae myself?

Comment: A nice fist course on the Standard Model, http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/0001283, which will contain the first equation (p65), but it won't cover the $\beta$-functions. For that you will need a course on QFT, see p395 of http://web.physics.ucsb.edu/~mark/qft.html, but that reference is quite advanced...